# Images aren't shown on mobile devices

Tags: html

I have some problem with images on mobile devices

I have images rendered as `<img src="http://externalsource/image.jpg"/>`
On regular browsers images are shown , on mobile devices not ...

Any Idea why this can happens ?

Comment: Maybe you have turned off Pictures on mobile. What mobile are you using ?

Comment: It could be that you've disabled picture loading. If not, you should provide a website address or at least some example code so we could tell you more.

Comment: mobiles can't show pictures over a certain size too

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
<img src="http://externalsource/image.jpg" alt="Celebrity Mobile" border="0" width="200" height="100"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an XHTML-style image tag, and a strict HTML4 parser would reject it. The [SGML-compatible syntax rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) require a space `<img src="http://externalsource/image.jpg" />` (and even then consider it to have a extra attribute named `/`, set to an empty string).

That said, I can't picture a real browser parsing HTML4 that strictly - it would never work on the tag soup that makes up the wild internet...